# How can I make atlas zoom on different polygons?

Tags: qgis, atlas

I'm trying to create an atlas and my last step is to zoom in on each exported picture over the red polygon. Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a common attribute of the red polygons different from other polygons?

Comment: Hi Kadir. Thank you for answering. It's all one dissolved layer. The different polygons will show up on the "preview atlas" feature. I don't think there is a common attribute, although I might not be understanding. I am relativelyt new to GIS.